# C function with variable arguments crashing

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I have written a function to help me debug a project:

```
    static void outputDebug(unsigned uintLineNo, const char* cpszFormat, ...) {
        char szPrefix[80], szOut[256];
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, cpszFormat);
        sprintf_s(szPrefix, sizeof(szPrefix), "%s %s %05ld %s\n"
                          , __DATE__, __TIME__, uintLineNo, cpszFormat);
        vsprintf_s(szOut, sizeof(szOut), "%s", szPrefix, ap);   
        va_end(ap);
        OutputDebugString(szOut);
    }
```

An example of this function:

```
    outputDebug(__LINE__, "AdapterInit(%s)", "Test");
```

Everything after the format string `AdapterInit(%s)` is optional, I've single stepped the function and it constructs the `szPrefix` without problems, as an example this would contain something like; `Apr 18 2018 07:33:07 01492 Adapter(%s)`

The next line `vsprintf` results in a exception:

```
    Unhandled exception at 0x0781e9ee (msvcr90d.dll) in ....
```

I can't see what I've done wrong, how can I resolve this?

[Edit]  The problem was in the line starting `vsprintf`, removing the unnecessary `%s` resolved the problem.

Working solution:

```
    static void outputDebug(unsigned uintLineNo, const char* cpszFormat, ...) {
        char szPrefix[80], szOut[256];
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, cpszFormat);
        sprintf_s(szPrefix, sizeof(szPrefix), "%s %s %05ld %s\n"
                          , __DATE__, __TIME__, uintLineNo, cpszFormat);
        vsprintf_s(szOut, sizeof(szOut), szPrefix, ap); 
        va_end(ap);
        OutputDebugString(szOut);
    }
```

Comment: Should you not be using `cpszFormat` as the format string to `vsprintf`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, looking at this now...will report back in a minute.

Comment: Besides the weird logic and wrong usage of `vsprintf_s` in regards to its format, you have a much worse problem: What is the *only* "argument" to [`vsprintf_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xa1a1a6z.aspx) supposed to be? It's *not* a pointer like `szPrefix` will decay to.

Comment: Why this question is tagged C++?

Comment: @Klaus, ok it is C, the project I'm working on is C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I gather correctly, you construct `szPrefix` as the new format string (by interpolating `cpszFormat` into it, adding a prefix). So the call to `vsprintf_s` should use *that*, instead of `%s`. I.e.

```
vsprintf_s(szOut, sizeof(szOut), szPrefix, ap);
```

Your chosen size for `szPrefix` (that 80) is also fairly optimistic. May be worth increasing it a notch or two.

Comment: szPrefix will never be larger than 80 bytes it only contains date time line number and formatting.

Comment: @SPlatten `szPrefix` will contain `cpszFormat` over which you have no control. What if it alone is to big? While you use the "safe" function so you won't overflow `szPrefix` there is still the possibility that the overflow-point will be a format code, leading to the string in `szPrefix` ending in a single `%` character which is invalid when you then pass `szPrefix` to the second `vsprintf_s` call.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I have complete control over it because I'm the developer that is working with it.  However I've now increased it to 256 as I modified the format string to include parameter names to be more helpful.

Comment: @SPlatten - You know how ancient programming wisdom goes. You may be the only developer now, but what happens in the future? What happens if the next guy is an axe wielding psychopath that stumbles and sees your ID on that commit? :)

Comment: @StoryTeller, that might be true, however this project is already ancient, I was brought it to bring it up to date (extend its life) before it is superseded by something else.